# Twilio: Rest API - Send Message - How to get message sid?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I want to send MMS using `Twilio REST API`. The message was sent successfully However, I am not able to get the unique `MessageSid` of the sent message.

I have already tried with `$result->sid` and  `$result->messageSid`.

**Current Code**

```
$result= $client->account->messages->create(
    $to, array('from' => $from,
               'body' => $message,
               'mediaUrl' => $mediaurl
              ));               

if (isset($result->messageSid))
    return $result->messageSid;
else
    return "";
```

Is there anything i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Any error you are getting ?

Comment: No error received.

Comment: Did you check  your Twilio account if message was sent successfully ?

Comment: try to print your `$result` variable like `print_r($result)` and check what response you are getting.. Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351102/sending-sms-via-twilio-in-php) once . .

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you check the output for the [first code sample on the documentation page for sending messages with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) then you will see that the returned JSON should have a `sid` property. Like this:

```
{
  "sid": "MMc781610ec0b3400c9e0cab8e757da937",
  "date_created": "Mon, 19 Oct 2015 07:07:03 +0000",
  "date_updated": "Mon, 19 Oct 2015 07:07:03 +0000",
  "date_sent": null,
  "account_sid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "to": "+15558675309",
  "from": "+15017250604",
  "body": "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?",
  "status": "queued",
  "num_segments": "1",
  "num_media": "1",
  "direction": "outbound-api",
  "api_version": "2010-04-01",
  "price": null,
  "price_unit": "USD",
  "error_code": null,
  "error_message": null,
  "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages/MMc781610ec0b3400c9e0cab8e757da937.json",
  "subresource_uris": {
    "media": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages/MMc781610ec0b3400c9e0cab8e757da937/Media.json"
  }
}
```

I just used similar code to you (I didn't send a media URL) and could echo `$result->sid`.

```
$result = $client->account->messages->create(
    'MY_NUMBER',
    array(
        'from' => 'MY_TWILIO_NUMBER',
        'body' => "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!"
    )
);

echo $result->sid;
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I am getting result like object(Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageInstance){....}. Does it matter?

Comment: You should be able to call `->sid` on that object.