# How to send text message through DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I tried looking all over the internet on how to setup and send text message(sms) through Dialogflow.
I am building an app where the Bot asks the user for their number and sends them a text message. Is there a tutorial? or anyone guide me I appreciate it?

Comment: I think you should go for Twilio for that. like after getting phone number from a user you have to set webhook and from that webhook call Twilio API and send text messages

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Nikhil, you need to use twillio APIs to send the SMS. 
Here is how it will work:

1. Dialogflow will ask user for phone number and store it in a parameter
2. Dialogflow will pass the phone number to the Webhook
3. The Webhook will make an API call to the Twillio API with above phone number
4. Twillio will send the sms
5. Webhook can return some success message to the Dialogflow
6. Dialogflow will return the message to the user.

Here is a link to the tutorial I have created for understanding dialogflow webhooks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cD9vU7Ubyg

You can refer to this link for sending sms in PHP via Twillio: [sending sms via twilio in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351102/sending-sms-via-twilio-in-php)